# Detecting Proper Usage of 'await' in Async Controller Methods Using C# and Xunit and NetArchTest

Tags: c#, xunit.net, netarchtest

I am using NetArchTest for enforcing certain design guidelines in .NET 7 Web API project.

Reference : https://github.com/BenMorris/NetArchTest/tree/master

I'm currently working on unit testing async controller methods in my ASP.NET Core project to ensure that they are properly using the await keyword within their method bodies. I'm using Xunit and Roslyn for code analysis and NetArchTest.Rules However, I'm encountering some challenges with detecting the correct usage of await in async methods, especially when the return type is Task.

**Code Details :**

```
      public class ControllerAsyncAwaitTest
      {
        [Fact]
        public void All_Controller_Methods_With_Async_Signature_Should_Use_Await()
        {
            // Arrange
            var controllerTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.IsClass && type.Namespace == "YourNamespace.Controllers"); // Update with your namespace

            var methodsWithoutAwait = controllerTypes
                .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
                .Where(method => IsAsyncMethod(method) && !MethodUsesAwait(method))
                .ToList();

            // Assert
            Assert.Empty(methodsWithoutAwait);
        }

        private static bool IsAsyncMethod(MethodInfo method)
        {
            return method.ReturnType.IsGenericType &&
                   method.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>);
        }

        private static bool MethodUsesAwait(MethodInfo method)
        {
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(method.GetMethodBody()?.ToString());
            var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();

            // Look for await expressions within the method body
            return root.DescendantNodes().OfType<AwaitExpressionSyntax>().Any();
        }
    }
```

I have few methods in controller which has already aync and await used but still running the above test it is failing

Could someone please provide insights or an alternative approach that ensures accurate detection of await usage within async methods, while handling the return type of Task?

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: What part is failing? Have you checked if 1) `IsAsyncMethods` detects all methods you expect it to **_and_ no more** (= no false positives?) 2) `MethodUsesAwait` detects all the usages you expect it to detect? In other words: Did you unittest your Unit Test ;D ?

Comment: Did you output the contents of `methodsWithoutAwait` to inspect manually what could be the issue?

Comment: BTW: It may not apply in your case, but it is perfectly fine for methods that return `Task` or `Task<TResult>` to _not_ use `await` in their body. In fact that would only be expected, if the `async` Keyword would be used, too. Which cannot be inferred from the return type. And also, but this certainly does not apply to you, there is `async void` ...

Comment: _And_ ... I am pretty confident, there already is a static analyzer you can use to detect this better than in unit tests. My Visual Studio warns me through "CS1998" - which could be configured to be treated as an error, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor-standswithMods for your reply. I am getting an error : Assert.Empty() Failure
Expected: <empty>
Actual:   [System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] in the Assert.Empty method

Comment: You shouldn't inspect source code like that in your unit tests. It's way too heavy. Unit tests are also not meant to be used to check if developers comply with coding conventions. Instead use static analyzers and let them promote warnings to actual errors. The performance is far better and the analyzers run in real-time. You can create configuration files that you can share amongst a team to ensure that all are using the same convention rules.

Comment: For example install [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md) via NuGet manager. then add a .ruleset file to the project. Opening this file in Visual Studio will give you a dedicated editor view (alternatively edit the XML file manually). Search for "await" and set warnings to "Error".

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode. for the suggestion :). It makes sense to me. I was just trying to experiment it with NetArchTest to enforce certain design guidelines in the application. Anyways I will try to install StyleCopAnalyzers via NuGet manager

Comment: Yes, it's so much easier to integrate and offers you so many rules you can manage, not only await.